# How can i save Multiple records to a csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a code that accepts multiple inputs and saves them to a CSV file. So far, it saves to a CSV file but it only saves one record.

```
def viewstudentdetails():
    name_array = list()
    age_array = list()

    def check_continue():
        response = input('Continue? [y/n] ')

        if response == 'n':
            return False
        elif response == 'y':
            return True
        else:
            print('Please select a correct answer [y/n]')
            return check_continue()

    while(True):
        std_name = input('Name: ')
        age_record = input('age: ')

        name_array.append(std_name)
        age_array.append(age_record)

        if not check_continue():
            break
        else:
            continue

    for name, age in zip(name_array, age_array):
        print(name, '\t', age)

    with open('studentfile.csv','a') as studentfile:
        studentfileWriter=csv.writer(studentfile)
        studentfileWriter.writerow([std_name, age_record])
        print("Record has been written to file")
        studentfile.close()
```

In the python idle, it shows

```
Name: peter
age: 56
Continue? [y/n] y
Name: paul
age: 50
Continue? [y/n] n
peter    56
paul     50
```

With what I wrote, in the CSV file, it is showing

```
paul     50
```

Expected result:
This is what its meant to show:

```
peter    56
paul     50
```

Comment: You are iterating your list(s) **before** you open the file, so simply move the iteration to within the ``with`` block and change ``writerow`` accordingly.

Comment: Further to what @MikeScotty said, `studentfileWriter.writerow([std_name, age_record])` you are writing to the file the last input, not elements from the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```py
studentfileWriter.writerows(zip(name_array, age_array))
```